# Laravel 4.1 w/ ccovey/ldap-auth

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I've gone ahead and followed all install instructions on https://github.com/ccovey/ldap-auth to try and get LDAP authentication with Laravel 4.1.

**adldap.php**

```
return array(
    'account_suffix' => "@xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx",
    'domain_controllers' => array("dc01.xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx"), 
    'base_dn' => 'DC=xxxxxxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx',
);
```

Now if I leave the adldap.php file as is above and run the following **route.php** file

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
 $credentials = array(
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password'
 );

 if($a = Auth::attempt($credentials))
 {
    return '<pre>' . print_r(Auth::user(), true);
 }
 else
 {
    dd($a);
 }
});
```

I get the following output

```
bool(false)
```

Which doesn't seem to make sense because I am using the correct username/password. I am also using the same configuration in regards to the domain and DCs when running ADSI from MSSQL so I know it works.

Now, if I change the **adldap.php** file to include a admin_username, admin_password I get the following error in my laravel.log

```
'Bind to Active Directory failed. Either the LDAPs connection failed or the login credentials are incorrect. AD said: Can't contact LDAP server'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever finds this post. I had to create the OpenLDAP directory and create a certificate from Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `admin_username` and `admin_password` and you also need to make sure that you have the correct setting for SSL/TSL it attempt to guess your targeted AD's settings automatically. Beyond that you may have some error with your `base_dn`. You can save a lot of hassle by using a LDAP client to check those settings much easily (something like [Softerra's LDAP browser](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/)).